# How do I change the value of author name in org-publish?

Tags: org-publish

Can I specify the value of author used in org-publish?

So far I can see that it is possible to exclude it but how do I change it?

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
    '(("org-project"
       ...
       :with-author nil
       ...)))
```

Update:  I can see that it comes from the `user-full-name` variable.  If I edit that then the name will change.  Is it possible to do this in any other way instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
#+author: name you choose
```

or let-bind the user-full-name in a src block. Something like this should work.

```
(let ((user-full-name "name you choose"))
   ;; publish commands here
  (org-publish "org-project"))
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I'll use the latter option.  Really obvious in retrospect.